# Implementing an optional relationship (enforced if FK not null)

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2000

Suppose we have these tables

```
Person( person_id, name, car_id )
CompanyCar( car_id, make, model, colour, plate )
```

Person.car_id should be a foreign key to CompanyCar.car_id, but I want Person.car_id to be nullable, so when I run sqlmetal to generate a linq-to-sql DataContext, I should get

```
class Person{
    int person_id,
    string name,
    int? car_id,
    CompanyCar companyCar //object references may hold null
}
```

and **if present**, Person.car_id should exist in CompanyCar.

According to the MSDN documentation I've read, this shouldn't be possible, but when we tried it, it worked. Few people seem to write or ask about this type of relationship online.

**Can I trust this foreign key to be enforced whilst also being optional?**

**UPDATE:**
Here is what SMSS generated when I asked for a CREATE script. Note the FK is created as NOCHECK **but** it does complain if I enter a CarID (e.g. 9999) which I know doesn't exist in the CompanyCar table.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person](
    [PersonID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [CarID] [int] NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PersonID] ASC
)WITH FILLFACTOR = 92 ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Person]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Person_CompanyCar] FOREIGN KEY([CarID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CompanyCar] ([CarID])
GO
```

(Apologies for name inconsistencies, job requires example naming)

Comment: Please show us the SQL you used to create the tables and foreign keys. If a foreign key is defined and a value is provided then it **will** be checked. If the value is null, it will not be checked

Comment: The with nocheck simply will not validate existing data that may be the the person table at the time of the alter table cmd.  The Fk will be checked on all new inserts and updates of the person table and deletes and updates of the pk in the car table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A FK reference on a nullable column works exactly as you're hoping.  When a non-NULL value is present, the FK constraint is enforced normally.  A NULL value is not checked by the FK constraint, as the value is currently unknown and it's impossible to say whether or not it violates the constraint.